# Get record from url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I know this is a really simple question but I guess my brain and google-fu isn't working so well today.

Let's say I have an Event, with Registrants, and they can pay for the event using one or more payments.

I'm trying to create a payment linked to a registrant (who is linked to an event).
So my payment should have both `registrant_id` and `event_id`.

My URL looks something like this: (nested routes)

```
http://mysite.com/events/1/registrants/1/payments/new
```

My controller looks something like:

```
def create
  @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
  @registrant = Registrant.find(:first, conditions: {id: params[:registrant_id], event_id: params[:event_id]} )

  @payment = Payment.new params[:payment]
end
```

I know there is a *much* better way to do it, but I'm having trouble with the wording to properly google it :)

What syntax should I be using to make the `.new` automatically aware of the `event_id` and `registrant_id`?

Comment: Do you mean how to pass in params[:event_id] and params[:registrant_id] ? If so, you'll need to `def initialize event_id, registrant_id` in your Payment model (or take an options hash and set the attributes indirectly). Or do you mean something else?

Comment: Is it bad practice to set the id attributes directly? I can just add them to the `attr_accessible` list then, right?

Comment: If they are just columns in a table, you can just set them. You'll probably want to pay attention to your foreign key definitions. Also, as RobHeaton mentions, the id might not actually exist as a database row, so generally if you are going to make ad-hoc associations like this definitely find the object first (as you are doing), then use the registrant.id attribute (rather than setting directly from a param).

Comment: BTW, I think I answered your actual question, but any reason why you are unable to use ActiveRecord associations to ensure correct build and query of objects?

Comment: Phil, I think I want to use associations, build etc, but the question was more that I don't know the syntax to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the discussion in the comments, there are several ways that the question can be addressed: the direct way and the Rails way.

The direct approach to creating objects that are related is to create the object using `new_object = ClassName.new` as suggested in the question. Then take the id of the created object and set that on  an existing object (directly with `existing_object.id = new_object.id` or through some other method if additional logic is required). Or set the id on a new object by defining a custom initializer, such as:

```
class Payment
  def initializer id_of_registrant
    @registrant_id = id_of_registrant
  end 
...
end
```

The advantage of this approach is that it allows you to assign registrant IDs that may come from a range of objects with different classes, without having to deal with unnecessary or perhaps incorrect (for your solution) inheritance and polymorphism.

The Rails way, if you always have a direct relationship (1 to 1) between a Registrant and a 'mandatory' Payment is to use a has_many or belongs_to association, as described in the Rails guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

For the example classes from the question:

```
class Registrant < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :payment
end

class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :registrant
end
```

You will want to use the appropriate migration to create the database tables and foreign keys that go with this. For example:

```
class CreateRegistrants < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :registrants do |t|
      t.string  :name
      t.timestamps
    end

    create_table :payments do |t|
      t.integer :registrant_id
      t.string  :account_number
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Of course, if you registrants only optionally make a payment, or make multiple payments, then you will need to look at using the has_many association.

With the has and belongs associations, you can then do nice things like:

```
 @payment.registrant = @registrant
```

if you have instantiated the objects by hand, or

```
 @payment.new(payment_amount)
 @registrant = @payment.build_registrant(:registrant_number => 123,
   :registrant_name => "John Doe")
```

if you would like the associations populated automatically.

The Rails Guide has plenty of examples, though in my experience only trying the most appropriate one for your actual use case will show if there are restrictions that could not be anticipated. The Rails approach will make future queries and object building much easier, but if you have a very loose relationship model for your objects you may find it becomes restrictive or unnatural and the equivalent associations are better coded by hand with your additional business rules.

Comment: Your answer pointed me in the right direction. Going back to the basics of associations in the Rails guides got me to where I need to be. I can use `@payment = @registrant.payments.new(payment_details)` and use `@payment.registrant.event.id` to get the event_id. But I feel like there should be a way to be able to just do `@payment.event.id`. The `event_id` doesn't get saved to the payment when I use this method.

Comment: OK, I think I see what you are saying. My question is this: what object relationships do you want? I'm assuming an event has multiple registrants, each with zero or more payments for the event. Can a registrant be associated with more than one event? If so, then you'll have to specify the event id during creation of a payment by a registrant. `payment.event_id` should work fine to set this (in the initializer), as long as you remember to save the change. Payment would also have a belongs_to association with the event.

Comment: Oh man. Somehow I forgot to add `belongs_to :event` in my Payment class. Now `@payment.event` works.

Answer (score 0):

It's not great practice to set `id` attributes directly, as the id might not refer to an actual database row. The normal thing to do here would be to use CanCan (https://github.com/ryanb/cancan), which seems like it would solve all your problems.

EDIT:

If you're not using authentication of any kind then I'd either put the load methods in `before_filter`s to keep things clean:

```
before_filter :load_event

def load_event
  @event = Event.find params[:event_id]
end
```

or define some funky generic loader (unnecessarily meta and complex and not recommended):

```
_load_resource :event

def self._load_resource resource_type
   before_filter do
     resource = resource_type.constantize.find params[:"#{ resource_type }_id]
     instance_variable_set :"@#{ resource_type }", resource
   end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but cancan is for users. My app is for administration purposes. Payments would be entered on behalf of customers.

Comment: If you're logged in as an admin (so `current_user` exists) then you could just define your permissions accordingly, eg. can create payment if is admin.

Comment: There's no plan to add authentication at all.